# Is it possible to sort items by worth in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

Is it possible to have the game sort my backpack's inventory by the amount of money each item is worth? Is there some something I could change in the games ini. files or is there some hidden setting that I'm completely oblivious to? ^-^

Comment: I severely doubt there's a hidden INI setting, but there's no option in game, though simply sorting by rarity (the default setting) does a pretty close job.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing, but common assault rifles, for example, are often worth more than uncommon pistols. So I still end up having to scroll through and check most of my items in order to drop the ones with the least worth. But if there isn't a faster way to do it then I'll just have to live it. :/ Thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 3):

No, but sorting by rarity is pretty much the same thing.